# WebException SSL Error in xamarin iOS app with service hosted on azure for EE mobile network in UK only

Tags: c#, ios, ssl, xamarin.ios

Details of service are mentioned below

- HTTP version 1.1
- NET Framework version v4.7
- Platform 32 bit

Protocol settings on azure are mentioned below

- Https only : On
- Minimum TLS version: 1.2
- Incoming Client Certificates : Off

App details are mentioned below:-

- Xamarin iOS
- Restsharp portable httpclient and  modernhttpclient used for service calls
- Info plist setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads set to yes

NOTE: This issue only occurs when a user is using EE mobile network. Everything works fine on wifi and o2 network.

Any hint, reference or suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could this be related to ipv6 not supported by the base url used for api calls?